# Tag for featureLayer

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not sure if this is the right place but I wanted to suggest, creation of a new tag called `featureLayer`. `featureLayer` is a new (ok not so new) component added to the arcgis javascript api. Around 130 questions have been asked associated with featureLayer and all are tagged under the `arcgis-javascript-api` tag.

I am not sure what are the requirements for a new tag to be created but a tag for `featureLayer` is quite important as it is still pretty new but most of the future questions associated with arcgis javascript will point in this direction. Also a lot of weight is being thrown behind it by ESRI and it also helps in loading much faster compared to other layers (Dynamic and Tile). To be honest `featureLayer` is graphicsLayer on steroids.

Hope I have made my case.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a good idea.  But there are problems.

Tags normally grow organically out of the ongoing process of new questions appearing and getting tagged appropriately or answers to old questions suggesting additional tags.

There exists no mechanism for wholesale application of a tag to old questions: to carry out your suggestion, someone would have to manually visit those 130 questions and tag them.  This would bump all 130 to the top of the active questions list, disrupting the continuity of that list for several days, which would please nobody.

If it were the case that essentially *all* the existing `arcgis-javascript-api` questions involved feature layers, then a simple solution would be to rename this tag and edit its wiki to reflect the modified meaning.  Unfortunately, there are almost 190 questions with this tag, so evidently quite a few are not related to feature layers.

I am also having trouble verifying the assertion that 130 of questions are associated with "featureLayer".  Searching finds only 26 with the [`arcgis-javascript-api` tag and "featureLayer"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=[arcgis-javascript-api]+%2Bfeaturelayer&submit=search), and just 40 have [that tag and the two words "feature" and "layer"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=[arcgis-javascript-api]+%2Bfeature+%2Blayer&submit=search).  Unless these searches are missing a lot, this is far from the 130 claimed.  Until this issue is cleared up, I am reluctant to take any action at all.

In the meantime, it makes perfect sense for people to tag *new* ArcGIS Javascript questions with `FeatureLayer` in cases where those questions focus on this component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @whuber. I am sorry, you are right, there are only 26. I actually only searched for `featureLayer` and got the following results back, http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=featureLayer, which made me think that lot of folks are asking about featureLayer. I would not recommend renaming `arcgis-javascript-api` to `featureLayer`. I would recommend a separate new tag `featureLayer` as and when the community finds that quite a lot of questions are being focused on `featureLayer`. Thanks

Comment: OK.  It sounds like the right action is to create that tag and then, as people see fit, they can apply it (to new or existing questions).  Would you be willing to create a Wiki excerpt?  If so, I don't think it takes anything special [to do it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1456) (although it may have to wait for a high-rep user to approve it).

Comment: sure will fill it out. Thanks

Comment: Done. http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-layer/info

Comment: Feature Layers also exist in ArcGIS Desktop in several forms ([IFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000) in ArcObjects, [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) in geoprocessing/arcpy, and vector feature-based layers in ArcMap). See also: [What's the difference between feature class and feature layer?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/whats-the-difference-between-feature-class-and-feature-layer)

Comment: Edited the Wiki entry to add the above and lots more info. The term "feature layer" is certainly not exclusive to the ArcGIS JavaScript API.